# Android ,calculate power per instruction?

Tags: android, arm, power-management

how does the .dex file instructions get executed on a processor & how
can i access the instructions that executed on ARM processor. i heard
that the instruction in android executed in blocks  & after that how
can i calculate the power per instruction that get executed on ARM

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on whether you are measuring power on real hardware or on a simulator. If you are measuring it on real hardware, you can write a microbenchmark consisting of many instances of the instruction that you want to profile. For ex:

```
_asm_{

add
add
add
...
add
add

}
```

Then you can divide the total energy and get energy/instruction.

If you are measuring this in a simulator, it should be much easier, but the answer would depend on the simulator that you are using.